# Menu with PushButtons

Tags: button, arduino, menu, esp32

I have a doubt about building a menu with pushbuttons.
Initially, I have to wait for a button to be pressed.
When someone goes, I have to open the option for the button pressed. I tried as follows but I was not successful. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```cpp
void loop() {
  int button1 = digitalRead(but1);
  int button2 = digitalRead(but2);

  while (button1 == LOW && button2 ==LOW) {};
  while (button1 == HIGH || button2 ==HIGH) {
    if (button1 == HIGH) {
      Serial.print("RFID")
      rfid_menu();
    }

    if (button2 == HIGH) {
      Serial.print("FingerPrint")
      fingerprint_menu();
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: You read both buttons; if both are `LOW`, the program will be stuck in the first `while` loop, because the button status isn't read again inside the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason your code gets stuck is because of the values button1 and button2 in the line:

while (button1 == LOW && button2 ==LOW) {};

when the code first runs, it assigns the values LOW to both of these variables.
While both of these values are LOW, the code within the loop (in this case, nothing) will loop forever until the value of button1 or button2 changes. However, as there is no code within the loop, this will never happen

to fix this, I would just delete that line of code. your code will still work as the other two while loops will only execute when one of the buttons is pressed (assuming everything is wired up correctly)